# unable to access php array for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
foreach($res as $key) {
    echo $key['id'].'<br>';
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Post VALUES('".$key['id']."')";

    if (mysql_query($sql) == TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
    }
}
```

For the first entry it works and adds it to the database but after that it gives the following error :
 Trying to get property of non-object

print_r($res) gives the following output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message] =>*******
            [created_time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-01-13 20:14:32.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

            [id] => 1413366785545501_1686416964907147
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [message] =>*****
            [created_time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-11-27 15:51:16.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

            [id] => 1413366785545501_1674032329478944
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [message] => The 'AD- MAD' competition :)
            [story] => KRITA // Chalk your art. added 4 new photos.
            [created_time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-10-07 19:02:12.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

            [id] => 1413366785545501_1662706990611478
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [message] => *****
            [story] => KRITA // Chalk your art. created a poll.
            [created_time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-10-02 21:06:05.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )

            [id] => 1413366785545501_1661659277382916
        )
```

I just want to store the id's in the database

Comment: post value of `print_r($res)`;

Comment: Show your array by print_r($array_name);

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: what is $link?....you have not defined it here..remove $link->error from code..it is giving error

Comment: The only thing that could produce that error in the snippet is `$link->error`. What is the value of `$link`?

Comment: $link =  mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD); even if i remove it . The data is not stored in database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You need to post more of your code.

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `Post` table? If there is more than just `id` as columns you need to specify which columns you are inserting data for.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) does not return an object, so you get the given error message when you try to use `$link->error`. Replace it with [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error();
```

You will get a clear error message why the SQL query failed.

But I have to repeat my note from the comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.